# UIImagePickerController в UIAlertController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage

есть UITableView
при нажатии на ячейку открываю UIAlertController
в нем картинка(UIImage) и и поле ввода(UITextField)

**цель**: при нажатии на картинку открыть UIImagePickerController , выбрать изображение и чтоб оно отобразилось в UIImage

**проблема**: при попытке открыть UIImagePickerController при клике на картинку в  UIAlertController дает ошибку "*Attempt to present UIImagePickerController on UINavigationContoller which is already presenting UIAlertController*" и UIImagePickerController не открывается

если пытаюсь открыть UIImagePickerController **не** в UIAlertController, все отлично работает

похоже косяк из-за вложенности

рад буду любым советам

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы увидеть ваш код для понимания.
Но, если я понял правильно, вам нужно открывать `UIImagePickerController` в `UIViewController`, который открывает `UIAlertController`. При нажатии на картинку в `UIAlertController` закрыть его и открыть `UIImagePickerController`.